# How to assert whether a text is present in table

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor and want to assert whether a newly added row contains the text which i have added.

Also i want to assert whether the particular text belongs to the header section.

I have tried to some extent but my code is failing.

Below is my code

```
 var row=element.all(by.repeater('dataRow in displayedCollection'));
   var col=row.all(by.tagName('td'));
   col.each(function(item)
   {
       item.getText().then(function(text)
       {
           

       })
   })       
    
   

})
```

Below is the HTML code
[image]

Below is UI
[image]

Comment: first I'd recommend you to look how to use `async/await`, it will be so much easier to write any script then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergey is correct, this would be much easier using async/await but using your example here is how I would do it.

Assuming that the newly added row is always the last row in the table you can probably do it something like this:

```
const rows = element.all(by.repeater('dataRow in displayedCollection'));
const relevantRow = rows.last();

relevantRow.getText().then(test => {
  expect(text).toContain(mySampletext);
});
```

If the new row is not always the last one, then the way to find it would be different. For example, if every time you added a row the table was sorted alphabetically, then you would need to filter the list of rows to find the one you are looking for, and then check that the text matches what you expect it to be.

You don't really need to get each `td` element unless you want to verify that the text in each column is correct. In that case you would probably do it similar to this:

```
const expectedText = ['someText', 'in order', 'by', 'columns'];
const rows = element.all(by.repeater('dataRow in displayedCollection'));
const relevantRow = rows.last();

const columns = relevantRow.$$('td');
let coumnTextMatches = true;
columns.each((col, index) => {
  col.getText().then(text => {
    columntextMatches = expectedText[index] === text;
  });
});

expect(columntextMatches).toEqual(true);
```

This may or may not be completely accurate. I just did it off the top of my head without testing it out but it should be pretty close to something like that.

For the headers it would be similar.

- get all the header elements
- iterate over each one and check that the text matches what you expect